# onClick problem with typescript 3.33 and react

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use an onClick property on a link with TypeScript and React:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { any } from 'prop-types';

function handleClick(this:any,name:React.ReactNode) {
  console.log('The link was clicked.');
  this.props.callbackFromParentSearch(name);
}

export const Suggestions = (props:any) => {
  const options = props.results.map((r: { id: React.Key; name: React.ReactNode; }) => (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick(r.name)}>
    <li key={r.id}>

      {r.name}

    </li>
    </a>
  ))
  return <ul>{options}</ul>
}

export default Suggestions
```

But this gives an error:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(event:
>   MouseEvent) => void'.ts(2322)
>   index.d.ts(1315, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick'
>   which is declared here on type
>   'DetailedHTMLProps,
>   HTMLAnchorElement>'

So how to use the onClick event properly in TypeScript & React?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to pass a function:

```
onClick={() => handleClick(r.name)}
```

However, even with that your code won't work, because your `handleClick` function requires to be bound in a way that `this` is an object that contains your props. That's not the case in your code.

Your component should work like that:

```
export const Suggestions = (props:any) => {
  const options = props.results.map((r: { id: React.Key; name: React.ReactNode; }) => (
    <a href="#" onClick={() => props.callbackFromParentSearch(r.name)}>
    <li key={r.id}>

      {r.name}

    </li>
    </a>
  ))
  return <ul>{options}</ul>
}
```

or like this:

```
function handleClick(props: any, name: React.ReactNode) {
  console.log('The link was clicked.');
  props.callbackFromParentSearch(name);
}

export const Suggestions = (props:any) => {
  const options = props.results.map((r: { id: React.Key; name: React.ReactNode; }) => (
    <a href="#" onClick={() => handleClick(props, r.name)}>
    <li key={r.id}>

      {r.name}

    </li>
    </a>
  ))
  return <ul>{options}</ul>
}
```

Comment: Actually in TypeScript, declaring the type of `this` as a first parameter [is allowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) (the first param will be omitted in the compiled JS). So that part of the code is valid, even if other parts aren't.

Comment: I didn't say it was invalid. But it didn't work together with how he called it.

Comment: It's incorrect to say that "your handleClick function required two parameters." It only requires one, since the `this` parameter [isn't included in the compiled output](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo(this%3A%20any%2C%20bar%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20bar%3B%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. It still wouldn't have worked though, right? I updated my answer to be more accurate. Can you agree with that?

Comment: That looks right now, only nitpick is I'd say "called in a way" not necessarily "bound in a way"

Comment: Cheers mate. :)